# using .filter to delete an item from an array of objects with react/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I am using .filter function of javascript to delete an element by it's ID in TypeMp3List from this array of objects. The format is like this :

[image]

The format I want to get after doing the filter when deleting for example the MP3 with `ID:33390` is this :

[image]

This is the code I've built so far :

```
  showDeleteConfirmation(value, id, index, thisHandler) {
    confirm({
      title: 'Voulez vous supprimer cette audio ?',
      content: '',
      okText: 'Oui, je confirme',
      okType: 'danger',
      cancelText: 'Non',
      onOk() {
       deleteMp3Request(id);
       var { extraitMP3 } = thisHandler.state;

        var array = [];
        for (var key in extraitMP3) {
          array.push(extraitMP3[key]);
        }
        console.log('array',array)

        const result = array.map(d => ({ 
          ...d, 
          TypeMp3List: 
              Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(d.TypeMp3List).filter(index => index !== id)
              ) 
        }))
        console.log('result',result)


       thisHandler.setState({result: result})
       NotificationManager.success("le fichier audio est supprimé avec succès !", "");
     },
     onCancel() {
     },
    });  
  }
```

Problem is after mapping and filtering the `console.log(result)` is giving me the same results of `console.log(array)`. It looks like there is something wrong with the  mapping and filtering and don't know exactly whats is it. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JackBashford Id is passed in

Comment: What does `id` in `showDeleteConfirmation` params mean?

Answer (score 3):

Because you use `Object.entries` - this returns a two-dimensional array (e.g. an array containing arrays), and within your `filter` you're checking if each array is equal to a number. It isn't. You want to access the first element of this array - so either a little destructuring:

```
Object.entries(d.TypeMp3List).filter(([index]) => index !== id)
```

Or more verbose array notation:

```
Object.entries(d.TypeMp3List).filter(index => index[0] !== id)
```

Comment: you're right about that but I am still getting the same results in both console logs. To mention that the delete is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

since you want a new array based on .filter verification, try returning the result of what you are comparing:

```
Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(d.TypeMp3List).filter((index) => {
        return index !== id
    )};
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake in using `filter` function.

In my opinion, you can pass each item to filter function and use its `id` to compare with `filterId`.

```
showDeleteConfirmation(value, filterId, index, thisHandler) {
...
   Object.entries(d.TypeMp3List).filter(listItem => listItem.id !== filterId)
...
```

Comment: this is not the problem I changed according to what you've said and nothing happened.